# What's the most important career advice for someone who is going to work in the U.S. for the first time?

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, recruitment, united-states, company-culture

I've been recruited to work at a large company overseas and this will be my first time working and living in the United States. I'm excited about the opportunity but part of me is worried about the fact that I'm from a third-world country and there might be huge differences between both countries in terms of work culture and practices.

What's the most important advice for someone who's about to come work in the U.S. for the first time at a large company? Are there any formalities I should be aware of? Is the work culture exclusive and different from any other place?

Comment: You may want to hint where you are coming from.

Comment: "You could be fired without any reason at any time, and nobody would care to support you in any way."

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure that your green card and/or H1B visa is always current. If it's not, your work engagement may be termimated immediately.
2. Don't do anything illegal because you will be deported immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about workplace etiquette and rules, it really depends where you come from. Some things will be the same and some won't, can you be more specific about where you are from and where you are going into in the USA? Off the top of my head, Americans generally don't lose much sleep over switching jobs or careers compared to some countries where people strive to have the same stable job for life, and this can affect workplace relations (e.g. people quit rather than complain or put up with bad management, and look for a new job instead of asking for a raise/promotion).

There are regional differences too...I am from the Midwest, and I've had friends go to work in the South, East and West Coast and all 3 had noticeable differences in workplace culture.

Answer (score 0):

As an outsider there is one overriding thing to always remember.

It's not enough to be as good as everyone else, you need to be **better** to get respected and get ahead. Be on your best behaviour both in and outside work. Work hard and respect the people, the laws, and the cultural values of your location.

This is where most people have issues, they get comfortable and they forget the basics. NEVER allow that to happen. Live as if you are being watched, and as if you are representing your people full time.